# Efficient ways to extract features in a pre-trained CNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, anaconda, conv-neural-network

Is there a more efficient way of extracting features from a data set then as follows:

```
def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 6, 6, 512))
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 6))

    generator = 
    ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(directory, 
    target_size=(Image_Size, Image_Size), batch_size = batch_size, 
    class_mode='categorical')

    i = 0

    print('Entering for loop...');

    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * 20 : (i + 1) * 20] = features_batch
        labels[i * 20 : (i + 1) * 20] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        print(i);

        if (i * 20) >= sample_count:
            break

    return features, labels
```

Due to the size of my data set this process is taking quite a bit of time and I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this ?

Thanks in advance :)

## Full Code:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from keras import losses
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Train_DIR = '/Users/eoind/food/train'
Test_DIR = '/Users/eoind/food/test'
Validation_DIR = '/Users/eoind/food/validation'

Image_Size = 200 # Size of input images to be scaled to 
Train_Samples = 6000
Validation_Samples = 3000
Test_Samples = 3000

num_epochs = 30
batch_size = 20
steps_per_epoch = Train_Samples/batch_size

conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape= 
(Image_Size, Image_Size, 3))

conv_base.summary()

print('Conv_Base Summary');

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 6, 6, 512))
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 6))

    generator = 
    ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(directory, 
    target_size=(Image_Size, Image_Size), batch_size = batch_size, 
    class_mode='categorical')

    i = 0

    print('Entering for loop...');

    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * 20 : (i + 1) * 20] = features_batch
        labels[i * 20 : (i + 1) * 20] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        print(i);
    
        if (i * 20) >= sample_count:
            break
    
    return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(Train_DIR, Train_Samples)
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(Validation_DIR, 
Validation_Samples)
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(Test_DIR, Test_Samples)

print('Extracting Features');

train_features = np.reshape(train_features, (Train_Samples, 6 * 6 * 512))
validation_features = np.reshape(validation_features, (Validation_Samples, 6 * 
6 * 512))
test_features = np.reshape(test_features, (Test_Samples, 6 * 6 * 512))

print('Reshaping Features');

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_dim=6 * 6 * 512))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

print('Model Summary');

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              loss=losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['acc'])

print('Compiling Model');

hist = model.fit(train_features, train_labels,
                 steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
                 epochs = num_epochs,
                 batch_size = batch_size,
                 verbose = 1,
                 validation_data = (validation_features, validation_labels))

print('Fitting Model');

train_loss=hist.history['loss']
val_loss=hist.history['val_loss']
train_acc=hist.history['acc']
val_acc=hist.history['val_acc']
xc=range(num_epochs)

fig1=plt.figure(1,figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(xc,train_loss)
plt.plot(xc,val_loss)
plt.xlabel('Number of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.title('Training Loss Vs. Validation Loss')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['Training', 'Validation'])
plt.style.use(['classic'])
fig1.savefig('loss.png')

fig2=plt.figure(2,figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(xc,train_acc)
plt.plot(xc,val_acc)
plt.xlabel('Number of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('Training Accuracy Vs. Validation Accuracy')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['Training', 'Validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.style.use(['classic'])
fig2.savefig('acc.png')

model.save('food_pretrained.h5') # Save model
```

## iPython Console Output

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_19 (InputLayer)        (None, 200, 200, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 200, 200, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 200, 200, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 100, 100, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 100, 100, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 100, 100, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 50, 50, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 50, 50, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 50, 50, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 50, 50, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 25, 25, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 25, 25, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 25, 25, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 25, 25, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 12, 12, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 6, 6, 512)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 14,714,688
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Conv_Base Summary
Found 6000 images belonging to 6 classes.
Entering for loop...
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12...
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are expecting, if the dataset is large, and you are using a GPU, there is not much to do than just wait for the whole dataset to be processed. This in any case will take less time than training a model on the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to say no, I don't think there is a more efficient way. The calculations have to happen and they are slow on a CPU especially. **The best you can do is avoid recalculations by transforming your dataset, saving the arrays, and then load them each time you train.**

I was going through the same thing until I broke down and bought a GPU... and my life has been much less stressful since. I highly recommend making the investment, even in a 1050 if you can't afford anything else. You may have to figure out how to deal with the limited GPU memory, but it will make things go much smoother for you.